# Untag/Remove a taxonomy term from a node

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms

I am inserting and updating node programmatically in drupal 7.When am updating I want to delete the taxonomy terms tagged in that particular node and have to insert new terms.

Please help me to untag the taxonomy terms of that node.the unset($node->taxonomy_field) is not working.Can anyone help me?

Comment: Have you tried to just set it to NULL or empty array() ?

Comment: You want to clear them from `node/%/edit` form or programatically unset them at some other point? Also, please post the code you are using, not just the one line, but a whole hook that is supposed to do the job, so we know when you wanted it to fire and could get the idea of how it works.

Answer (score 1):

With Views Bulk Operations for Drupal 7, you can execute arbitrary PHP scripts.

In order to bulk-delete a specific taxonomy term, you can make a View that shows all content with the particular term you want to remove: Be sure to add a Relationship in the View like "Content: Taxonomy terms on node" so you can filter out content with the terms you want to keep.

Then in the same View, you'd add a VBO field to execute an arbitrary PHP script. VBO no longer uses $node but rather $entity, so you can pass through the following script modified from Dave Parrish's answer above (where *field_name_of_taxonomy_term* would be the name of the Term Reference or Entity Reference field where you save the taxonomy terms on the node):

```
for ($i = 0; count($entity->field_name_of_taxonomy_term[$entity->language]) > $i; $i++) {
    if ($entity->field_name_of_taxonomy_term[$entity->language][$i]['tid'] == 'TID to Remove') {
        unset($entity->field_name_of_taxonomy_term[$entity->language][$i]);
    break;
    }
}
node_save($entity);
```

Answer (score 0):

`unset` should do the trick.  In my case, my taxonomy field was called `field_genre` and here is how I removed a taxonomy from a node.

```php
for ($i = 0; count($node->field_genre[$node->language]) > $i; $i++) {
    if ($node->field_genre[$node->language][$i]['tid'] == $tid_to_remove) {
        unset($node->field_genre[$node->language][$i]);
        break;
    }
}
node_save($node);
```

Comment: It might be helpful to indicate where you've placed your code.